# Why my wordpress website title is not showing when I copy the link to facebook and other social network?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I am building a website like this www.arpandasphotography.com

I have set up the title for the page from the general setting. But when I copy the link to somewhere such as Facebook messenger or whatssap it shows "No Title" as the name. How do I change it?

Comment: Please give more detail, like code samples, so we can help you out.

Comment: I did not use any coding, I simply built it using Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

There is a facebook debugger for situations like this:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

It says you're missing og:description.